# MS Access multiple filter in the same field satisfying all of them

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select, where-clause

I am fairly new to access. I have a table similar to the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wF5.png)
I am trying to create a query that shows suppliers that are capable of BOTH Grinding and Milling. 
This the outcome I am Hopping to get

```
A    Grinding
A    Milling
B    Grinding
B    Milling
```

and Ignore the rest. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where
    t.capatibilty in ('Grinding', 'Milling')
    and exists (
        select 1
        from table1 t1
        where 
            t1.supplier = t.supplier 
            and t1.capatibilty in ('Grinding', 'Milling')
            and t1.capability <> t.capability
    )
```

If Grinding and Milling are the only two possible values, this can be simplified a little:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from table1 t1
        where 
            t1.supplier = t.supplier 
            and t1.capability <> t.capability
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the columns returned you can use `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename as t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where supplier = t.supplier and capability <> t.capability
)
```

or:

```
select * from tablename
where supplier in (
  select supplier from tablename
  group by supplier
  having count(*) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find out just the suppliers with both capabilities, you would join your table to itself like so:

```
SELECT Table1.Supplier
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.Supplier = Table1_1.Supplier
WHERE Table1.Capability="Grinding" AND Table1_1.Capability="Milling"
```

Your result for that however will just be:

```
A
B
```

If you wanted to include the capabilities on separate rows then you have to link the table one more time to itself like so:

```
SELECT Table1.Supplier, Table1_2.Capability
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.Supplier = Table1_1.Supplier) 
INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_2 ON Table1.Supplier = Table1_2.Supplier
WHERE Table1.Capability="Grinding" AND Table1_1.Capability="Milling"
```

And your result will be:

```
A   Milling
A   Grinding
B   Milling
B   Grinding
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In my table I have over 200 different capabilities; Is there a way it can ask me for which capabilities am I looking for. Again many thanks.

Comment: If you're sticking with finding a supplier that matches 2 capabilities, then just replace the WHERE clause with  
`WHERE Table1.Capability=[Capability1] AND Table1_1.Capability=[Capability2]`